# Graphviz node split

Tags: nodes, graphviz

Okey so how to split node in *graphviz* in the middle to divide node in two parts with different colors and how to write text in multi line columns.

I know Graph viz is HTML based, but I can't make any workaround I need some examples.

I want to get something like this:

```
|------|
|Title |<-- red background
|------|
|text1 |
|text2 |<- green background
|______|
```

My example code looks like:

```
digraph G {
  node [shape=box] <- don't know how to make it divided Up/Down parts
  node1 {label = "Title"}
  node2 [label = "text1\\text2"]  <- Don't know what to do here 

  node1 -> node1 ;
  node1 -> node2 ;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you want to use [HTML-like-labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html)

```
digraph structs {
    node [shape=plaintext]
    struct [label=<
        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
            <TR><TD PORT="title" bgcolor="red">Title</TD></TR>
            <TR><TD PORT="text" bgcolor="green">text1<br />text2</TD></TR>
        </TABLE>>];
    // example edge
    struct:title:w -> struct:text:s
}
```

[image]